# Bind:after not calling assigned method in server side blazor - c# - mudblazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-binding, blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to use the @bind-Value and @bind-Value:after to call a method after the bind has happened, but i am either getting an error in my code or the call to the method won't happen.

With this i get error Compiler Error CS0407 'return-type method' has the wrong return type

`<MudCheckBox Label="@R["Show title"]" Disabled="(!MayEdit && !MayDelete)" @bind-Value="@OptionsModel.Title_Visible" T="bool" @bind-Value:after="IsDirty"></MudCheckBox>`

If I add brackets to the method it complains about Compiler Error CS1503
Argument '1' cannot convert from "bool" to "System.Action"

If i put it in a lambda it will compile but won't call the method when the checkbox changes
`<MudCheckBox Label="@R["Show title"]" Disabled="(!MayEdit && !MayDelete)" @bind-Value="@OptionsModel.Title_Visible" T="bool" @bind-Value:after="(() => IsDirty())"></MudCheckBox>`

The method is in the class file ChartPropertyView.razor.cs, the Checkbox is in ChartPropertyView.cs
`public override bool IsDirty()`

IsDirty() doesn't get colored yellow in VS Professional 2022 V. 17.7.7 and can't be hovered for infos as normally

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code, function get colored yellow:

```
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<input @bind-value="aa" @bind-value:after="()=>{IsDirty();}"></input>

@code{
    private string aa="abc";
    public bool IsDirty(){
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried changing the line to match yours, sadly it still doesn't recognize the method.